# Another "#1054: Unknown column in 'field list'" mystery

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

Have looked for any solution but unsuccessfully...
The mystery is about body of my few functions. I presented two of them below. They are pretty the same but Fun1 works fine and Fun2 doesn't. The error is as in topic - "Unknown column in 'field list'". I've noticed that it rather depends on declared variable type - if it's string (like tadnotation) there is no problem met, if it's time, decimal, enum, it causes errors. Can someone explain it to me? And of course I'm also searching for the solution, so every tip is welcome.

Inputs are the same for every function:

```
(`vtable` ENUM('user','client', 'daily_operation','monthly_operation'), 
`vclient_id` SMALLINT,
`vuser_id` SMALLINT, 
`vid` INT,
`vedition_id` TINYINT)
```

Fun1:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getAdnotation` (`vtable` ENUM('user', 'client', 'daily_operation', 'monthly_operation'), `vclient_id` SMALLINT, `vuser_id` SMALLINT, `vid` INT, `vedition_id` TINYINT) RETURNS TINYTEXT CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

DECLARE tadnotation TINYTEXT;

SET @tadnotation = CASE
    WHEN vtable = 'daily_operation' THEN 
        (SELECT adnotation FROM daily_operation WHERE (client_id = vclient_id AND user_id = vuser_id AND id = vid AND edition_id = vedition_id) LIMIT 1)
    WHEN vtable = 'monthly_operation' THEN 
        (SELECT adnotation FROM monthly_operation WHERE (client_id = vclient_id AND user_id = vuser_id AND id = vid AND edition_id = vedition_id) LIMIT 1)
END;
RETURN @tadnotation;

END$$
```

Fun2:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getStartTime` (`vtable` ENUM('user', 'client', 'daily_operation', 'monthly_operation'), `vclient_id` SMALLINT, `vuser_id` SMALLINT, `vid` INT, `vedition_id` TINYINT) RETURNS TIME
BEGIN

DECLARE tstart_time TIME;

SET @tstart_time = CASE
    WHEN vtable = 'daily_operation' THEN 
        (SELECT start_time FROM daily_operation WHERE (client_id = vclient_id AND user_id = vuser_id AND id = vid AND edition_id = vedition_id) LIMIT 1)
    WHEN vtable = 'monthly_operation' THEN 
        (SELECT start_time FROM monthly_operation WHERE (client_id = vclient_id AND user_id = vuser_id AND id = vid AND edition_id = vedition_id) LIMIT 1)
END;
RETURN @tstart_time;

END$$
```

Table (only 'daily_operation' because 'monthly_operation' is similar):

```
CREATE TABLE `daily_operation` (
  `client_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `edition_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL,
  `duration_minutes` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `duration_hours` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `adnotation` tinytext
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What works is if I change SET-CASE clause with:

```
IF(vtable = 'daily_operation') THEN
    SET @tstart_time = (SELECT start_time FROM daily_operation WHERE (client_id = vclient_id AND user_id = vuser_id AND id = vid AND edition_id = vedition_id) LIMIT 1);
ELSEIF(vtable = 'monthly_operation') THEN
    SET @tstart_time = (SELECT start_time FROM monthly_operation WHERE (client_id = vclient_id AND user_id = vuser_id AND id = vid AND edition_id = vedition_id) LIMIT 1);
END IF;
```

Comment: Just a copy-paste mistake - inputs are writen correctly. I have already edited the post, thanks. Answering the question, error occurs only when I check function like SELECT Fun1(...). In real code it doesn't bother but it also doesn't allow to pass transaction block.

Comment: Cal you add full create table/function queries? (```SHOW CREATE TABLE ...```/```SHOW CREATE function ...```). My bet at this stage -- typo in column name or input variable name. Also, it might be return value type mismatch.

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE? Have you tried to change SP to replace SET / CASE by IF / SELECT INTO @var syntax?

Comment: Is it ok right now? I've tried bunch of combinations and using IF clauses it tends to work more often.

Comment: IF / SELECT INTO works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me assignment with [CASE expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) is a bit confusing (hard to read) so I'd use [CASE clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) **with INTO @var** instead:

```
BEGIN
CASE
    WHEN vtable = 'daily_operation' THEN 
        SELECT start_time INTO @result FROM daily_operation WHERE (client_id = vclient_id AND user_id = vuser_id AND id = vid AND edition_id = vedition_id) LIMIT 1;
    WHEN vtable = 'monthly_operation' THEN 
        SELECT start_time INTO @result FROM monthly_operation WHERE (client_id = vclient_id AND user_id = vuser_id AND id = vid AND edition_id = vedition_id) LIMIT 1;
END CASE;

RETURN @result;
END
```

Note, you do not need to DECLARE @session_variables used in SP.

Comment: Typed-in in a hurry and it's ok. What may be the explanation why it's a rubish when using SET-CASE? Currently I don't have enough time to validate this solution for my further works but I'll soon and I'll get you informed. Thank you by now!

Comment: I do not know what exactly is causing your issue. It works in my system 'as-is' (I used you create function table syntax. As you have not supplied your monthly_operantio table create syntax I used daily_operation create table syntax to create monthly one). It might be some columns named differently there, gut I'm guessing. If I rename start_time column in monthly_operantio and call the SP getStartTime('daily_operation', 1, 1, 1, 1), I still got error 1054 when using your syntax.

Comment: Don't know how did it happen but somehow I was missing one column. So the error was extremaly obvious. Anyway, thank you for the help. Finally, I changed my code a lot and currently I don't have such case expressions but your solution was completely satisfying for my past needs.