# IF statement sub query optimisation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select 
if(`num`>99, (select `value` from `sub` where `id`=`main`.`num`), "") as `result`
from `main`
```

This all works fine but MySQL is very inefficient as it needlessly executes the `sub` select statement when `num` is below 100, even though the result of the sub query will not be used when `num` is below 100.

Is there a way to make it more efficient so the sub query is not executed when the if statement is false, as this obviously slows down the command by executing a sub query that doesn't need to be executed.

I tried a CASE which has exactly the same issue.

TO BE CLEAR: This is about MySQL executing a sub query when it doesn't need to.  This is a waste of resources and slows down the overall query, thus very inefficient.  The statement above I just made up to simply highlight the sub query being needlessly executed issue.

Comment: I'm not sure about IF() function, but CASE certainly would not execute the subquery if WHEN returned false.

Comment: As I said, same with a CASE.

Comment: *same* what? CASE does not execute a subquery when it does not need to. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258713/10498828

Comment: I tested with a case and it does execute, as well as evaluate. See the comments in your link

Comment: The comments in my link state that CASE works as expected and as documented. Check the code in that answer. Also, check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dHxAfVH7As125wh66rkrJ7/0 and this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ewrXZ2nLKtcwsZsA8cnha/0 If you can reproduce the behavior of CASE that you claim that you experience then post a fiddle with that code.

Comment: What "proof" do you have that it executed the subquery?  (I tried a different query and came to the opposite conclusion.)

Comment: You could add `SLEEP(1)` to the inner select list, thereby slowing down the query.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a join like below

```
select
case when `num`>99 then t.`column` else '' end as result
from `main_table` m
left join `tbl` t 
on m.`num`=t.`id` and `num`>99
```

Comment: This does not solve or address the issue as you are still in essence executing the sub query, this time as a left join.

Comment: @JustinLevene Joins are better than sub query most of the times; and in this case definitely. Also JOINS <> Sub query. Please search and you'll see multiple reasons why we should do a join instead of sub query.

Comment: Because with a join, the search is done on all rows, the idea of a sub query is that the search will only be done on rows that require it, however MySQL is not behaving.

Answer (score -1):

the empty ("") is requred?

if not:

```sql
(select `column` from `tbl` where `id` = `num`) as result
FROM `main_table`
WHERE `num` > 99
```

or use JOIN select (I not run it, only reference):

```sql
SELECT column AS result
  FROM tbl
  LEFT JOIN main_table
    ON tbl.id = main_table.num
  WHERE main_table.num > 99
```